# Can't see one component in a JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class Box {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        BoxFrame frame = new BoxFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class BoxFrame extends JFrame{
    public BoxFrame(){
        setTitle("BoxGame");
        setSize(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
        DrawComponent[] component = new DrawComponent[4];
        component[0] = new DrawComponent(0, 0, 20, 20);
        component[1] = new DrawComponent(400, 0, 20, 20);

        add(component[0]);
        add(component[1]);//here the problem is
    }
    public static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 600;
    public static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 400;
}

class DrawComponent extends JComponent{
    private double left;
    private double top;
    private double width;
    private double height;
    public DrawComponent(double l, double t, double w, double h){
        left = l;
        top = t;
        width = w;
        height = h;
    }
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(left, top, width, height);
        g2.draw(rect);
        g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fill(rect);
    }
}
```

here is my code, it is not complicated. but when i try to draw two component, the window only draw one. this piece of code,when i get rid of the first component, the window will draw the second one. and i have looked up JFrame.add method in javadocs, but did not find what the error is,plz help me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the default layout manager of a `JFrame` which is a `BorderLayout`. When you `add` your second component, it will replace the first. (Both are added to the `CENTER` cell.)

If you want to use components to show the boxes I suggest you lay them out without overlap.

Otherwise I'd suggest you draw all boxes on the same component.